# Urban heat island effect during winter time?

Tags: climate-change, temperature, climate-models, urban-climate, winter

Say a given populated area is considered an "urban heat island", this would mean that during summer, temperatures will be higher in that area.

But what about winter? One could argue that higher temperatures during winter are actually a positive effect. Therefore, I'm trying to understand what can be considered a negative effect during winter time?

Comment: 'Urban heat island' is purely a descriptive word for the effect on temperatures of urbanization.  Whether you consider it a positive or negative depends on your perspective. In a cold climate a degree or two of warmth might reduce heating bills but it might also disrupt winter sports opportunities (which might be trivial), or adversely affect ecosystems, e.g. raised temperatures might allow insects such as mosquitoes to breed more successfully.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  Whether warmer cities are "positive" or "negative" is broad or subjective and not really answerable on a science site.  What exactly do you mean by a "negative effect"?

Comment: @gerrit gas emissions for example

Comment: That doesn't really clarify the question.  Some gas emissions might be modified by urban heat islands - but other s might not be causal

Comment: the heat island effect might make the area colder in winter,heat that rises will pull in colder air.i have no idea if this is a reallity but it is possible.you need to add more information into your question as it is now it is a bit opinion based.